# Error message 'System.Security.VerificationException : Operation could destabilize the runtime.' while extracting text from pdf using iText7

Tags: c#, itext7

I am trying to extract text from .pdf files using iText7.
It was running fine few days ago but now following error is coming.

> System.TypeInitializationException : The type initializer for 'Common.Logging.LogManager' threw an exception.
>   ----> System.Security.VerificationException : Operation could destabilize the runtime.

on local machine code is running fine issue is coming on server.

I have tried updating iText7 package from Manage Nuget Packages

Following is the code I am using to extract text from PDF

```
public static string ExtractTextFromPDF(string LocationWithFileName)
        {
            StringBuilder PDFText = new StringBuilder();
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(LocationWithFileName));
            LocationTextExtractionStrategy strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
            for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); ++i)
            {
                PdfPage page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
                PDFText.Append(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy));
            }
            pdfDocument.Close();
            return PDFText.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: As you can read the issue occurs for `Common.Logging.LogManager`. Are you sure that you have an appropriate common logging version in your project?

Comment: @mkl you are right. It was due to different versions of Common.Logging.
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Do you want to make that an answer yourself?